# Maven doesn't appear when eclipse is opened from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, terminal

When I double click on the eclipse icon, Maven options appear when I right click on my Mavenised project.

When I open eclipse from the command line however, it doesn't appear, even though I know it is already mavenised and has a pom.xml file.

Any ideas as to why it happens and what I can do to get Maven menus to show up when opening eclipse from the terminal.

Comment: Maybe the maven plugin is not activated if you launch it from the command line? In the about dialog you see all the activated plugins.

Comment: And which OS is this?

Comment: Different eclipses...?

Comment: Its on windows, Im using a git bash shell to open eclipse kepler I dont think I am using different eclipses as I open it from the same directory from both the the terminal and from the icon..